# Is it possible to merge Windows Recycle bin and the Linux trash folder on a dual-boot?

Tags: linux, windows

Is it possible to merge Windows Recycle bin and the Linux trash folder? I have Windows 7 and Deepin, a Ubuntu based distribution, installed as a dual-boot on my machine. I am wondering if it possible to merge the recycle bin and the trash folders together so that in either operating system when i open the recycle bin and can see and erase files deleted from both operating systems?
I assume that is possible to change the configuration of Ubuntu's Trash so that it is sent to windows %recyclebin% folder, and it would then be recognized as trash by windows.

Comment: The Windows Recycle Bin and the Ubuntu Trash folder have different internal structures.

Comment: Do you know if either would simply recognize all files in the trash folder? Then i could just trick the one into using the others folder.
@DavidMarshall

Comment: See my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As another used mentioned [on this post](https://superuser.com/questions/692907/what-is-the-path-of-the-recycle-bin-directory), the folder of the recycle bin of each user in a different directory. The structure goes like this:

```
\$Recycle.Bin\%SID%
```

where SID is the ID of the user. So, to access this folder you have first to learn what is your SID. The proper command to do this in windows is the following:

```
wmic useraccount get name,sid
```

(credits goes to [this article](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/registry/ht/find-user-security-identifier.htm))

The ID would have a structure similar to the following:

```
X-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX
```

So, once you find youd ID, you can open that dir to check if it's the right one, simply by typing the location in windows explorer, like this:

```
 \$Recycle.Bin\X-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX
```

After that on Ubuntu the last 2 steps you have to follow are the following. Go to your Ubuntu trash directory, which is:

.local/share/Trash

Copy everything and paste it on the Windows recycle bin directory. Then you can delete the content of the original folder. After that, you'll have to create a "sym link" with the following command:

> ln -s /media/name of your second location/Trash /home/bob/.local/share/Trash

(credits goes to [this article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1917852))

Haven't test it before, but I see no reason for not to work. I hope I helped you.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Windows renames the deleted file to $R<number>.<extension> and creates a file called $I<number>.<extension> to contain the information to restore the original file. Ubuntu has two directories called files and info in the Trash folder to perform the same function.